# Worksheet_SelectionChange Only If Cell Value is >= 1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have been using this syntax to fire off an event to create a worksheet when certain cells are clicked, but now my issue is that a blank worksheet is created bc the cell has few 0 values.  How can I not fire this event if the cell value is 0?  I thought using the Target.Count > 1 would handle this, but it does not.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Range("A" & Target.Row) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Value` property - the `Count` property of the `Range` will tell you how many cells are in the `Range` - not the `Value`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub '<-- new line to check cell value

    Debug.Print Range("A" & Target.Row) 

End Sub
```